# How do I get Mac system icons, as in the Finder?

Tags: cocoa

I want to set the images in my outline view to the system icons, just like on the left in the Finder. I want to get icons like Application, Documents, Desktop, etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a method in NSWorkspace that allows you to set custom icons to folders and files:

```
- (BOOL)setIcon:(NSImage *)image forFile:(NSString *)fullPath
    options:(NSWorkspaceIconCreationOptions)options
```

*Sets the icon for the file or directory at the specified path.*

Answer (score 10):

Use NSWorkspace's [iconForFile](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/iconForFile:): method

```
NSImage *icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"/Applications/"];
```

edit:

take a look at these files, are they what you're after? Your question is a little hard to understand

```
$ ls /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Toolbar*FolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarAppsFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarDesktopFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarDocumentsFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarDownloadsFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarLibraryFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarMovieFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarMusicFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarPicturesFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarPublicFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarSitesFolderIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarUtilitiesFolderIcon.icns
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `-[NSWorkspace iconForFileType:]`, and pass constants from IconsCore.h (filtered through `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode`, of course).

Comment: You get all in an OutlineView with let image = NSWorkspace.shared().icon(forFile: it.url.path)

Answer (score 0):

This article on [Creating icns Icon Files](http://murphymac.com/creating-icns-icon-files/) should cover what you want to do. There is also an article on [creating an icon so that it looks similar to the standard folder icon](http://murphymac.com/make-a-custom-leopard-folder/), which is good for consistency. Hope that helps.

Of course, this isn't really programming related.